# How to embed a YouTube channel into a webpage

Tags: video, youtube, embed, youtube-channels

Can anyone suggest how I embed a youtube channel into a webpage - I am getting conflicting information from various sites, ideally using the custom player if possible? thanks

Comment: Use official Google API here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Comment: kindly change the solution to @Matthew Lock's solution

Answer (score 99, accepted):

YouTube supports a fairly easy to use [iframe and url interface](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to embed videos, playlists and all user uploads to your **channel**: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

For example this HTML will embed a player loaded with a playlist of all the videos uploaded to your channel. Replace YOURCHANNELNAME with the actual name of your channel:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=YOURCHANNELNAME" width="480" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: +1 for coming back to an old question and giving a top answer

Comment: At least this one produces an output. For some reason the javascript examples listed on this page and elsewhere don't output anything on my page.

Comment: This works, but it only gives 100 videos. How do you make it show you the whole channel?

Comment: @zabs +1 for giving a +1 for coming back to an old question and giving a top answer.

Comment: not working for me, perhaps something changed on youtube? in dev tools i'm seeing calls to https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?style=json&action_get_user_uploads_by_user=1&username=UC9LJW6SJZb8UVolFueZlXeA returning status 400.

Comment: Where would be the channel name located?? The public channel name does not work.

Comment: And how can I embed a subchannel that I have under the same account? I am currently struggling with this.

Comment: yes this will work but you need to edit the answer to use https not http. It now works after for me. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me with the `listType` paramater. I just took it out: https://www.youtube.com/embed/?list=UULFZXXi0dM4r7-sKFNo1kGlwg

Comment: This appears to be outdated and no longer working.

Answer (score 20):

In order to embed your channel, all you need to do is copy then paste the following code in another web-page.

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=YourChannelName&synd=open&w=320&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
```

Make sure to replace the **YourChannelName** with your actual channel name.

For example: if your channel name were **CaliChick94066** your channel embed code would be:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=CaliChick94066&synd=open&w=320&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>
```

Please look at the following links:

[YouTube on your site](http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite)

[Embed YouTube Channel](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=4c414f514bc3f690&hl=en)

You just have to name the URL to your channel name. Also you can play with the height and the border color and size. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks for that - I probably should have stated I am trying to get this displayed without the Google Gadgets bar at the bottom - I guess I may have to use the API to create a more customised player.

Comment: This approach is broken now.  Gives GET http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/videoshow/videoshow.css 404 (Not Found) ifr:411
GET http://www.youtube.com/profile_style?user=UC5RELOfGjybISISo9wTs8KA&callback=_callbacks_._0hrv2nl60 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 9):

Seems like the accepted answer does not work anymore.
I found the correct method from another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811403/6368026

> Now you should use:
>
> > http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=USERID
> > And the USERID is your youtube user id with 'UU' appended.
>
> For example, if your user id is TlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg then you should put UUTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg. If you only have the channel id (which you can find in your channel URL) then just replace the first two characters (UC) with UU.
>
> So in the end you would have an URL like this:
>
> > http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UUTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg

Comment: I don't know, why the accepted answer shouldn't work - in 2022 it is working. Allthoug i upvoted your answer, because it is also working...

Comment: this also, appears to not be working in 2022 along with the accepted answer.

Comment: This works. Just replace `http` with `https`.

Answer (score -6):

I quickly did this for anyone else coming onto this page:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u1zgFlCw8Aw?fs=1"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  allowscriptaccess="always"
  width="425" height="344">
</embed>
</object>
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YGkT5/)

Comment: The question is about embedding the channel, not a single video.

Comment: that is not relevant for this question.