# What's the best way to embed a youtube channel dynamically on a website (prefer wordpress)

Tags: youtube, wordpress, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I'd like to be able to embed youtube videos from a channel onto a wordpress page both via a shortcode and a widget. There are plenty of youtube channel galleries out there, but after looking for hours, I found none that contain all these features:

- dynamically add videos (ie - new video on channel appears on web-page)
- pagination for many videos
- uses actual youtube player, not some flash player (that's not compatible with iOS)
- has both shortcode and widget (full page & sidebar channel lists)
- displays title info from youtube

I'm open to an existing plugin, but am willing to write my own if it comes to that, I'm spending too much time on this.

Thank you SO community!

Comment: i am unsure that it will match your search criteria but tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209217/how-to-embed-a-youtube-channel-into-a-webpage

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing my options, tubepress looks like the way to go. It's not that pretty, but I can style it.