# How to embed Youtube user_uploads for new (Google +) Youtube channel id's?

Tags: youtube-api

Been searching for the API to embed a Youtube channel's `user_uploads` for channels which have the new `channel_id` (starting with UC) instead of a user name but did not find any working solution. According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#list), there is only the possibility to embed a player with `user_uploads` for a `USER ID`. Are there any (undocumented?) parameters to achieve this?

Example of working iframe embed with `user_id`:

> http:// www.youtube.com / listType=user_uploads&list=USERNAME

Not working:

> http:// www.youtube.com / embed?listType=user_uploads&list=UC....xxxxx (Google + style channel id)

Answer (score 5):

The posted answer does not work anymore.

Now you should use:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=USERID
```

And the USERID is your youtube user id with 'UU' appended.

For example, if your user id is `TlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg` then you should put `UUTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`. 
If you only have the channel id (which you can find in your channel URL) then just replace the first two characters (`UC`) with `UU`.

So in the end you would have an URL like this:

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UCTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`

BTW. you can append `&index=1` to specify which video should be played.

> See answer on [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051589/4489917)

Answer (score 1):

Never seen such a username. Do you have a link to a user (youtube website) with such a username ?

Update.

It looks like it is a part of the new V3 api from youtube and I filed a bug report at the youtube dev forum since it wont't work withe the user_uploads iframe

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6463

> For example this channel
>
> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpAOGs57EWRvOPXQhnYHpow
>
> then ID is UCpAOGs57EWRvOPXQhnYHpow
>
> Now try to load this
>
> http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UCpAOGs57EWRvOPXQhnYHpow
>
> This isn't working, Only with real usernames