# youtube feeding url is not working with my account

Tags: youtube, rss, feed

Hi,

I am using this URL to get feed from my youtube account

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=
```

you have to put your user name at the end. However, my account is rather new and I dont know what my user name is. So I went to my settings and under user ID there is a long unintelligible word which I didnt chose. I tried that and didnt work.

I then tried with an older account I have and it actually shows an user name on my profile page which I remember I chose when I created the account. I tried the feed with that one and it does work so does it mean newer accounts dont have a user name?? How can I use the feed URL then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the feed from a youtube channel, you can use this link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=<channel_id>
```

or

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=<user_name>
```

Where you have to change  for a valid channel_id or  accordingly.

Examples:

- https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=Microsoft
- https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCE_M8A5yxnLfW0KghEeajjw (Apple Inc.)

Comment: Thank you but I am actually trying to get something like this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=saintseiyainfored2 this URL works with channels that have a user name but mine doesnt have it.

Comment: @CainNuke, I understand. Maybe there's some configuration in your channel. I tried with my youtube channel and it works: https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=newnemesis666 . You're free to answer, but, can you share the name of your youtube channel?

Comment: Thats the thing, my channel doesnt seem to have a name, only a channel ID which is the one at the end of the URL I sent you. Newer channels seem to be like this because I have an older channel and that one does have an user name so your example works with that.

Comment: @CainNuke try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811403/4092887) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45342740/4092887). If none of them works, My suggestion is use Youtube API for get the videos you want based on channel_id. I don't have more ideas, sorry. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I think I will just give it up.

Comment: @CainNuke, I make a [question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/HHStBtXWZUU;context-place=forum/youtube) in Google Chrome Forums. If you really want to get this results, try with the Youtube API or post a question there. Don't give up :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind help although Im not that concerned about this question. Its my latest one which is driving me crazy. I have asked here and there but nobody seems to know the answer.

Comment: @CainNuke what is your channel_id? - I want to give it a try to answer your question.