# HTML YouTube to Show All Videos?

Tags: html, video, youtube, web, feed

Anyone know how to add the full upload feed from YouTube to a website using html coding??? I've been able to get single videos, but haven't found anything regarding all videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) you can retrieve all videos on a specific channel.

If you just wanted to embed a full upload feed from a channel, as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209217/how-to-embed-a-youtube-channel-into-a-webpage) states you can use the [channel embed code](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/youtube/how-to-use-youtube-features/TOLiiakr_-g), for example:

```
<script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&amp;up_channel=YourChannelName&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=390&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to add that code to my coding, but for some reason nothing pops up. I was experimenting just with one video previously and the viewing window would pop up. Now I am very new to html coding, so there is quite possibly an error on my part.

Comment: I would say fork this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austinpray/G5GhH/) and have a go at modifying it to use a channel. Also here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimoneGianni/NmvA9/) example of using the Youtube Data API to acheive the desired result.