# Youtube player iframe embed not working for my channel

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I am trying to add a youtube player for my channel using iframe on my website.

[I picked up code from here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)

The channel is - http://youtube.com/channel/UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ

I have used the channel id -  **UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ** in the below html code snippet on my website.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="400" height="225" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I get error inside player -

> An error occurred. Please try again later

Also, I could see in the network tab that I am getting a 400 [BAD REQUEST] http response for the request

```
https://www.youtube.com/list_ajax?action_get_user_uploads_by_user=1&style=xml&username=UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ
```

The error is

```
{"errors": ["The URL contained a malformed username.", "Invalid request."]}
```

I need help with embedding this channel using channel id on a webpage. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The list param should be the username and not the userID, try and check your username here https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

like so for example:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="400" height="225" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UKFDrumandBass" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it would get all the videos uploaded by the user UKFDrumandBass

If you want to embed videos from a channel and not from a username check this thread [How to embed a YouTube channel into a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209217/how-to-embed-a-youtube-channel-into-a-webpage)

Comment: I have used channel id in the example I posted above.

On https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced, 

I could see youtube user id and youtube channel id but the player doesn't work with both.